# Bash-shell grammar issue about Ternary operator and printf function

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

```
cat file
chenghuanghuijia jidianzhong 100 E20128
pannybudaqiu gujihuihenwan -1 
shuijiao buxihuan 20 E20138
huijiakan babamama 10
```

I want get the result that when the line contains E2[0-9]*$ , the end of the line will be printed, if the line not contain E2[0-9]*$, the end of the line will be printed NULL or \n.

Here is my code:

```
awk '{printf("%s\n",($NF~/E2[0-9]*$/? "E2.*$" : NULL))}' file
```

The output as below:

```
E2.*$

E2.*$
```

but I want to print E20128 & E20138, So I verified my code with deleting " "

```
awk '{printf("%s\n",($NF~/E2[0-9]*$/? E2.*$ : NULL))}' file
```

Then it comes the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf("%s\n",($NF~/E2[0-9]*$/? E2.*$ : NULL))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                    ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf("%s\n",($NF~/E2[0-9]*$/? E2.*$ : NULL))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                               ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf("%s\n",($NF~/E2[0-9]*$/? E2.*$ : NULL))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                ^ syntax error
```

So I think is the grammar issue of Ternary operator( _?x:y) or printf function.
please support me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/.*\(E2[0-9]*\)$/s//\1/;//!s/.*//' file
```

- `/.*\(E2[0-9]*\)$`: capture strings matching `E2[0-9]*` and output it using backreference (`s//\1/`)
- `//!`: if there is no matching string, clear the line(`s/.*//`)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this awk

```
awk '{$0=$NF}!/E2[0-9]*$/{$0=""}1' infile


{$0=$NF} : for each line replace the complete line by the last field.

!/E2[0-9]*$/ if the line not match the regex

{$0=""} : substitute the complete line by nothing

1 : print each line
```

Comment: could you please make a explanation for the command , the command seems excellent.

Answer (score 0):

After think for a while ,below works:

```
awk '{printf("%s\n",($NF~/E2[0-9]*$/? $NF : NULL))}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the `E2...`, a simple `grep` should be enough:

```
grep -o "E2[0-9]*$" file
```

`-o` is the option for extracting the matched pattern